# how to publish android library module to jcenter without sources?

Tags: android-studio, publish, android-library, bintray, jcenter

I want to upload an android library module(.aar) for public use. But i don't want to share the actual sources. Can it be done using any plan (open source/paid) of bintray?

Answer (score 1):

Bintray's jcenter is a repository for open-source software. The package required to have an open source license, which, in turn requires either sources artifacts or a link to sources to be present.